# Como guardar a senha no script R no package ‘encryptr’?

Tags: r, criptografia, senhas, password

Eu fiz isso:

```
library(encryptr)
genkeys()
```

E criei a senha: `0)]30l^8`

```
password<-"0)]30l^8"
data(gp)
write.csv(gp, "gp.csv")
encrypt_file("gp.csv")
```

Meu problema: Como inserir, automaticamente, a senha em `decrypt_file("gp.csv.encryptr.bin", file_name = "gp2.csv")`

Eu preciso disso para descriptografar muitos arquivo em pouco tempo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É impossível fazer isso, ao menos no momento em que estou escrevendo esta resposta. Se tu for até a [página do pacote no github](https://github.com/SurgicalInformatics/encryptr/), especificamente na parte das [issues](https://github.com/SurgicalInformatics/encryptr/issues/1), vai ver que um dos programadores [respondeu o seguinte em 25 de fevereiro de 2019](https://github.com/SurgicalInformatics/encryptr/issues/1#issuecomment-467142887) (grifos meus):

> Many thanks for this and the work in the pull request. It is greatly appreciated.
>   Along with some other changes, I have incorporated your suggestions in the latest push.
>   **All but the option of exposing the password option.
>   This was designed in this way intentionally to avoid having passwords written into scripts. This seemed to the team exactly what we were trying to avoid.**
>   Is there a particular situation you see in which the password must be included in the script? If there is a good argument we will include. But there are lots of good reasons not to do this.
>   Many thanks again.

Logo em seguida, [ainda em 25 de fevereiro](https://github.com/SurgicalInformatics/encryptr/issues/1#issuecomment-467172736), o mesmo programador escreve o seguinte (grifos meus novamente):

> **I guess I feel pretty strongly about not allowing users the option to make a mistake with a password. Together with wanting to go to information governance authorities and say we are using a system in which the password is not recorded in the script.**
>
> An alternative (that may be over thinking it) is to have genkeys_() specifically for developers that allows that option, but is not included in the standard package vignettes etc.
>
> Thanks again for this help and discussion. I should have said above that I haven't incorporated the tests, but will do with a PR when we conclude this thread.

Ou seja, por opção dos programadores, não é possível utilizar as funções do pacote com a senha escrita em algum no lugar dentro do script. Portanto, infelizmente, não é possível fazer o que a pergunta pede.

Comment: Estive explorando o pacote encryptr e descobri que ele é uma maquiagem do pacote openssl para torna-lo muito mais acessível ao usuário. Vou ter que fazer engenharia reversa para trabalhar diretamente no openssl.